# LILO vga option

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel

In `LILO` config file (`/etc/lilo.conf`) what's the difference between specifying `vga` option in `Global` section and when specifying it in `per-image` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vga` option is a bit strange: it is processed by the kernel, not by Lilo. However, unlike most such options, for historical reasons, it is not passed on the kernel command line, but using a binary protocol. Nonetheless, specifying the option in the `Global` section is equivalent to specifying it in every `image` section.